# Different links extraction from a text file?

Tags: python, regex

My problem is that I have a non-structured .txt file like the one below that contains different links because there is a signature in each link:

[Sample of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NafrM.png)

What I want is to extract all the links that begins with http:// web.alphorm.com

I used the regex shown below:

```
matchObj = re.findall(r'(http:// web.alphorm.com/.*&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJF2PMCJPGKXG2GEA)"}',
                      string)
```

But it doesn't really gives me what I want. It shrinks the text file and gives me the searched links, but along with other undesirable links and text!

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Do you really have a space between `http://` and `web.alphorm.com`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put some actual sample data from the text file in it. See [**_Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors_**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: lessons is json type have you tried parsing it in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` in your regex is **greedy**, meaning the parsing engine will match the `http://web.alphorm.com/` of the **first** match, and the `&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJF2PMCJPGKXG2GEA` of the **last** match, and *everything in between*.

Try this:

```
matchObj = re.findall(r'(http://web.alphorm.com/.*?&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJF2PMCJPGKXG2GEA)"}',string)
```

The addition of the `?` will make the matching *lazy*, matching as little as possible.

Note: I also removed the space between `http://` and `web.alphorm.com`, as I presume that's a typo.